# Get the value of a cell with handsontable - Error : method is not a function

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I want to get the value of one cell of my handsontable grid in my ajax callback function. So I can get my grid because when I do a `alert(hot);` it just tells me `[Object][Object]` and no 'undefined'. But now, I'm trying to get one value and select one cell like this :

```
alert(hotTraitement.getDataAtCell(1,1));
```

And Firebug tells me :

> hotTraitement.getDataAtCell is not a function

What am I doing wrong ?

**EDIT :**

I declare my handsontable in a window.load like this :

```
$(window).load(function(){
            var data = [];


            var container = document.getElementById('tab_traitement');
            var hotTraitement = new Handsontable(container, {
                data: data_traitement,
                stretchH: 'all',
                minSpareRows: 1,
                observeChanges : true,
                rowHeaders: false,
                colHeaders: false,
                contextMenu: true,
                ...

            });
});
```

And I pass my `hotTraitement` in parameter like this :

```
 function insertTraitementCallback(responseObject,ioArgs,hotTraitement)
```

And it seems working because I get [object Object] and no "undefined".

If I'm wrong then what should I do to have hotTraitement available in my callback ?

**EDIT 2 :**

In my function, I just try to display the content of one cell for now, to see if I can get my `hotTraitement`:

```
function insertTraitementCallback(responseObject,ioArgs,hotTraitement)
{
    alert(hotTraitement.getDataAtCell(1,1));
}
```

And Firebug tells me that "hotTraitement.getDataAtCell is not a function".

**EDIT 3 :**

```
function insertTraitementCallback(responseObject,ioArgs)
            {
                var idTableau ='tab_traitement';
                var table = 'traitement';
                var indexCell = 1;
                var jsonobject = eval(responseObject);
                console.log(hotTraitement.getDataAtCell(1,1));
                callback(jsonobject,data_traitement,idTableau,table, indexCell,'insert');               
            }
          var data = [];
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $(window).load(function(){
            container = document.getElementById('tab_traitement');
            hotTraitement = new Handsontable(container, {
                data: data_traitement,
                stretchH: 'all',
                minSpareRows: 1,
                observeChanges : true,
                rowHeaders: false,
                colHeaders: false,
                contextMenu: true,
                ...
            });

        var table = 'traitement';


        $('#submit_button_traitement').click(function()
        {

            var id_essai = $('.session').text();
            arrayDataIDTraitement.length = 0;
            arrayDataCodeTraitement.length = 0;
            var idTable='id_traitement';

            $.post("ajaxUpdate.php",{arr:data_traitement,id_essai,table,idTable},insertTraitementCallback,'json');

            for(var i =1; i<data_traitement.length-1 ; i++) //Création du tableau pour les listes déroulantes
            {                   
                arrayDataIDTraitement.push(data_traitement[i][1]);
                arrayDataCodeTraitement.push(data_traitement[i][0]);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: where is that function? could you please just post the entire code?

Comment: @ZekeDroid I edited my post

Comment: no as in post literally your entire javascript. You have a very common javascript scoping issue but we can't see it unless you show us where you're declaring your functions and where you're calling them from

Comment: @ZekeDroid I edited again

Comment: well see there you go. your function is in an entirely different script. why don't you move in inside your main script? also, try removing the window.load part, the first document.ready should be enough for your case

Comment: @ZekeDroid When I declare my hot in the window.load, it seems to get my hotTraitement because when I alert it, I get [Object object]. But when I use a method on it, it doesn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

You have a scoping issue. hotTraitement will not be available in the callback. You need to pass hotTraitement to the ajax settings options and then use that variable in the callback. The context in which the callback is executed is different.

Comment: I think I resolved this problem, maybe not. I edited my post for more details.

Comment: If hotTraitement is really in an other scope, what do you advise me to resolve that ?